# Unable to fetch array into an EJS file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to display an appropriate error message that I am pushing in an array 'errorsList' and sending it to ideas/add.ejs as the context. In the EJS, i am iterating over errorsList and fetching the elements. The webpage displays an error saying errrorsList is not defined.

I have tried to pass the JSON directly instead of putting it into some variable just to check, still in that case it gives me an error as errorsList is not defined

App.js

// Process form

````
    let errorsList = [];

    if(!request.body.title) {
        errorsList.push({ text: 'Please add a title' });
    }
    if(!request.body.details) {
        errorsList.push({ text: 'Please add something' });
    }
    console.log('Errors List: ', errorsList);

    if(errorsList.length > 0) {
        const context = {
            errorsList: errorsList, 
            title: request.body.title, 
            details: request.body.detail, 
            pageTitle: 'Ideas'
        }
        response.render('ideas/add', context);
    }
    else {
        const context = {
            pageTitle: 'Ideas'
        };

        response.render('ideas/ideas', context)
    }
});```


add.ejs

<div class="container">

    <% errorsList.forEach((error) => { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <%= error.text %>
        </div>
    <% }) %>


Here i get the error as errorsList is not defined
````

Comment: Can you try defining with type any like "let errorsList: any = [];"

Comment: try `context.errorsList.forEach(...)`

Comment: @matrixersp I tried still while figuring out what the issue was... I got the error 'context' is not defined

Comment: That's cause the `errosList` is empty, try to console log something in the 1st & 2nd if statement

Comment: @matrixersp it is empty at the beginning. is it something related to inititalising the array like let errorsList = [];?